# Text to speech for Gujarati language

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to implement Text To speech.I have tried these possible solutions for Gujarati language but it has not worked:

m_TTS.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("gu_IN"));

m_TTS.setLanguage(new Locale("gu"));

m_TTS.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("gu"));

Comment: i am facing same issue please help

Comment: any success with this?